# How do I send a route to a device?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

Is it possible to generate a link that can send a route to a phone and open the app automatically?

I'm looking to send a link to drivers in our fleet, alternatively is there an API endpoint which can send a route to a device for me?

I've tried sending a web link for a route to the phone and it shows the route correctly in the phone's browser but I don't know how to start that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a share link in the app using 2 coordinates -
https://share.here.com/r/54.106285,-1.080375/52.598712,-2.033751